# Sublime Text 3 with python on MacOSX -- Module missing its methods

Tags: python, macos, multiprocessing, sublimetext3

With  `"import multiprocessing"` and `dir(multiprocessing)`:

Using Sublime Text 3 latest -- 3083 I get:

```
 [ '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'multiprocessing']
```

Using terminal I get:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Feb 10 2015, 03:29:19) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> dir( multiprocessing)
['Array', 'AuthenticationError', 'BoundedSemaphore', 'BufferTooShort', 'Condition', 'Event', 'JoinableQueue', 'Lock', 'Manager', 'Pipe', 'Pool', 'Process', 'ProcessError', 'Queue', 'RLock', 'RawArray', 'RawValue', 'SUBDEBUG', 'SUBWARNING', 'Semaphore', 'TimeoutError', 'Value', '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', '_multiprocessing', 'active_children', 'allow_connection_pickling', 'cpu_count', 'current_process', 'freeze_support', 'get_logger', 'log_to_stderr', 'os', 'process', 'sys', 'util']
```

How do I fix?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: multiprocessing module is missing the module methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying to run this code within a Sublime plugin, or via the Sublime console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>). If so, you are using the version of Python that ships with Sublime (3.3.3 for ST3 at the moment) for internal use. While it does include the `multiprocessing` module, it is a stripped-down version only including the methods/classes that Sublime needs. There are a number of other modules in the "normal" Python standard library that are not included in Sublime, including, for example, `Tk`/`tkinter`, `idlelib`, `turtle`, `asyncio`, etc.

If you want to play with `multiprocessing` on your own, you'll need to run your `.py` file through the version of Python installed on your computer, either using a build system or through [`SublimeREPL`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL).